# Player too slow, can't jump, and moves fast diagonally

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My current issues are that the player is extremely slow no matter what I set my moveSpeed to, the player won't jump, and the player moves fast when moving diagonally. The script is shown below.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
    public float jumpForce = 10f;
    public float groundCheckRadius = 0.2f;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private bool isGrounded;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"); //Get horizontal input
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"); //Get vertical input

        Vector3 moveDirection = (transform.right * horizontalInput + transform.forward * verticalInput) * moveSpeed;
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + moveDirection * Time.deltaTime); //Move the player using Rigidbody's MovePosition method

        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, groundCheckRadius, groundLayer);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

1. I've tried changing Update to Fixed update, and Time.deltaTime to Time.fixedDeltaTime (resulted in player moving insanely fast no matter what moveSpeed was set to
2. I've tried changing Input.GetAxisRaw to Input.GetAxis, resulting in movement being too smooth, but I'm going for responsiveness
3. I've tried removing Time.deltaTime, resulting in choppiness and the player clipping through walls.
4. I've tried changing the method of jumping to changing rb.velocity.y to jumpForce when Space is pressed and the player is grounded.

Comment: How many frames is the game running? And, is the timeScale set to 1?

Comment: It's running 700 ish fps, and the timescale is set to 1.

Comment: It makes sense that the character is faster diagonally; (1, 0, 1) is a larger vector than (1, 0, 0).  As far as the jumping, have you checked to see that `isGrounded` is actually true when you expect it to be?

Comment: MovePosition will not follow physical collision, you would need to modify the object's velocity for that

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out. I also fixed the diagonal movement problem by normalizing the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to moving using velocity instead of transform fixed the physics issues, editing movespeed through the inspector instead of the script fixed the slow movement, and normalizing the velocity vector fixed diagonal movement being faster.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Unity script inside the Inspector tab. Typically, the variable value you set in the inspector tab overrules the value you set in script.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Sorry I can't upvote it, since I need at least 15 reputation :/